# Slow data retrieval from SQL Server 2008 vs 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-performance

We have a WCF service which uses a SQL Server database. When the service starts it loads data from the database into memory. When we use SQL Server 2000, it takes 1 min to load and come online, but when used SQL Server 2008 R2, it takes more than 8 min to complete the same task.

There is huge table which we load from database. When we check SQL Profiler it takes more time in retrieving data from that table.

Do we have to change any settings in SQL Server 2008 to achieve faster data retrieval or do we have to make changes to the WCF service in connection string or anywhere else?

Database is not a upgraded one from 2000 to 2008. It was created on 2008 and tested with it.

Exact query is

```
SELECT a.Col1,
       IsNull(a.Col2, '') Col2,
       IsNull(a.Col3, '') Col3,
       IsNull(a.Col4, '') Col4,
       IsNull(a.Col5, '') Col5,
       IsNull(b.Col2, '') bCol2
FROM   Table1 a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 b
         ON LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(a.Col5, ''))) = LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(b.Col1, '')))
ORDER  BY a.Col1
```

I noticed that with "Order by" clause its taking more time compared to without "Order by" it takes 4sec. So, i added a clustered index on Table1.Col1 to see any change, still it takes more time of about 8min

System details: Windows 7 32bit, Corei5, 3GB memory

SQL 2008 Version details:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (Intel X86)   Apr 22 2011 11:57:00   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Please someone help us solve this issue.

Comment: Show us something! E.g. the **table structures** (columns, their datatype, nullability etc.) and **indexing** - what indexes are there already? What does your **query** look like? Did you have a look at the query **execution plans**?

Comment: service pack version?  hardware? disk subsystem?

Comment: `LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(a.Col5, ''))) = LTrim(RTrim(IsNull(b.Col1, '')))` is a horrible join predicate. It won't be able to use any indexes. You should clean your data to remove any leading spaces then you can use `ON EXISTS (SELECT a.Col5 INTERSECT SELECT b.Col1)`

Comment: Thanks for the response @MartinSmith But is it the actual reason for this performance issue or is it with Order by clause. As I mentioned in my question it was taking time with Order by Clause whereas the join condition is same in both cases of with & without Orderby clause.

Comment: You would need to look at the execution plans with and without the `order by` and on 2000 vs 2008 to understand the difference in performance. But changing the join condition as previously suggested will allow better plans anyway.

Comment: Yeah you are correct @MartinSmith. I think we found the answer. When I changed the Join condition (removing LTrim & RTrim), it executed in 8sec. This is what we need. Thanks for you answer.